# Showing the first data point in line-chart y-axis with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using a line-chart with [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). My problem with this chart is that it by default isn't showing the first label on the y-axis, which I need, and that it seems that there's no option for showing i either.

In my case, I'm only going to show a graph that goes between 1, 2 and 3, and that's what the y-axis also needs to show. Right now though, it only shows the labels 2 and 3 (except for the decimals..) on the y-axis.

This is my lineChartData:

```
lineChartData = {
        labels: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
        datasets: [{
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(197,171,30,1)",
            pointColor: "#c5ab1e",
            pointStrokeColor: "#c5ab1e",
            scaleOverride: true,
            scaleSteps: 2,
            scaleStepWidth: 1,
            scaleStartValue: 1,
            data: [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1]
        }]
    }, options = {  
        scaleFontColor: "#f00",
        datasetStrokeWidth: 5
    };
```

Here is a jsfiddle of how it looks like now: http://jsfiddle.net/qe5hL/
(Imagine that the decimals don't show and that the y-axis only should show 1, 2 and 3)

Is there a simple way to solve this - to show all labels on the y-axis with chart.js?